# Change Startup Page of a WordPress website

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I have an installed WordPress website.

I'm working on the site, therefore, I want to show a constructor page for the internet user. I have created a page which called ***first.html*** and I change the ***.htaccess*** file like below

```
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex first.html
```

Now when I enter my domain name on the browser I can see the first.html. This is working properly.

I'd like to see my changes by entering the domain and page name on the browser like

**www.mydomain/index.php**

or

**www.mydomain/wp-content/themes/XXXTHEME/index.php**

However, my theme pages don't work.

How can I achieve to do this?

Comment: If my answer worked for you, could you please upvote it and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making changes in .htaccess, I'd suggest you to use this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/maintenance/

Answer (score 0):

Simply name your html file "index.html"

Web servers most commonly parse the index.html file firstly (unless told otherwise) and if it is not found, it proceeds to index.php

This also allows you to simply change that ".html" part to ".php" to see the website you are working on, without installing plugins that clutter your database or making unnecessary changes to your .htaccess file.

Comment: Hey, I have done you what you suggested. As you said, when I navigate my domain, index.html is working. However, even though I run the www.mydomain/index.php, still index.html is running instead of the index.php

Comment: did you change anything in your .htaccess file? please revert to previous version if you done so

Comment: Yes, I removed the changed which I made in the .htaccess file. There it no DirectoryIndex tag in it now.

Comment: ok, it should work perfectly fine now. this is the default preset way it's supposed to work :)